# Using PDOStatement::fetch() like mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

So, I'm trying to use PDO for a log-in form in order to prevent MYSQL injection, and I've come across a problem. While previously I used code like this:

```
$fuser = $_POST['fusername'];
$fpass = $_POST['fpassword'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE username='$fuser' AND password='$fpass'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num==1) {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
extract($row);
$_SESSION['auth'] = "yes";
$_SESSION['uname'] = $fuser;
$_SESSION['lev'] = $accesslevel;
```

I am now attempting to do this with PDO (ignore the changes in variable names)

```
$loginemail = $_POST['lemail'];
$loginpass = $_POST[('lpassword')];
$loginpass = sha1($loginpass);
$query = $hsdbc->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = 
:loginemail and password = :loginpass');
$query->bindParam(':loginemail', $loginemail, PDO::PARAM_STR, 75);
$query->bindParam(':loginpass', $loginpass, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
$query->execute();
if ($query->rowCount() == 1 ){
```

However, I'm unsure how to do the last part where I assign the session variables. I've looked into fetch and was possibly thinking FETCH_CLASS might be the answer but I'm not sure

Comment: so, other variants didn't attract you?

Comment: `$row = $hsdbc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  $_SESSION['uname'] = $row['fuser'];`  (I'd suggest against using `extract()`).

Comment: what about just try fetch() before asking?

Comment: The answer to this question is right on the mysql_fetch_assoc manual page.

Comment: I did try it, but it didn't work. Rocket Hazmat, does that work for multiple variable assignments? I thought fetch moved the cursor on by 1 each time

Comment: mysql_fetch_array is moving it as well. what is your problem?

Comment: @user3508084: Yes, it does move the cursor.  `->fetch()` returns the entire row (not one column), then moves the cursor.  How did it "not" work?  What happened?  What does `var_dump($row);` show you?

Comment: With mysql_fetch_array I understand that it stores it as an array of values that can all be reached by using $ then the column name e.g. $forename. However, I can't get $hsdbc->fetch() to function like that

Comment: Use `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` to retrieve row data.

Comment: @user3508084: That's not correct.  `mysql_fetch_array` returns an **associative array** (which is *also* what `$hsdbc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` returns).  You are able to access `$forename` because of `extract($row);` (which I suggest against).  Try accessing `$row['forename']`, this is how you access values from arrays.

Comment: Excellent, it's now working. I'm just getting used to this guys, so cut me a little slack. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

First, do **NOT** use `extract`, is ugly and bug prone.

Second, you are missing the fetching part:

```
if ($query->rowCount() == 1 ){
    $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['auth'] = "yes";
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $data['fuser'];
    $_SESSION['lev'] = $data['access_level'];
}
```